# differentiation under integration

Tags: measure-theory, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, weak-derivatives

If I choose my $X=\{(x_{1},x_{2},..,x_{n})\in \mathbb{R}^n| \ x_{1}+x_{2}+...+x_{n}=1\}$, and $\int_{\Omega}(f(x,\omega))dP(\omega)=\int_{\Omega}\bigg[max\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}(t-r_{i}),0\bigg)\bigg]^\alpha dP(\omega)$ where $\alpha \geq 1$, $t$ be a constant and $r_{i}'s$ are random variables.

Will the differentiation(with respect to $x_{i}$) under integration  theorem work here? Because my X is not open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Theorem says for $f:X\times\Omega \longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $,  X should be a open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. But I have seen that people used this theorem for this case. What is the reason behind this ?

Comment: Openess of $X$ is a sufficient condition. It is not a necessary condition. I.e., differentiation under the integral sign is guaranteed to to work when $X$ is open. When $x$ is not open, it may work, it may not. For this particular $x$ and integration, both the function and the set are highly regular, so it is hardly surprising that differentiation under the integral sign still works. You just have to put more effort into justifying doing so than relying on the big generic theorem.

Comment: Idea: reduce the problem to the known case. Obviously, $X\cong\Bbb R^{n-1}$.